# How do I go from one div to a specific slide in a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose i have two pages. One is **index.html** and another is **page.html**. In **page.html** i have a slider which has 9 slides (using the plugin [`StackSlider`](https://github.com/codrops/StackSlider)). Now,  when i will click in a link in **index.html**, i want to go to a specific slides say slide no 4 in **page.html**.

How can i do that?

I tried the following but it did not work

**Here is my index.html code**

```html
<body>
  <a href="page.html#one">go to 1st slide of page.html</a>
  <a href="page.html#two">go to 3rd slide of page.html</a>
</body>
```

**Here is part of code for page.html**

```html
<section class="main">
  <ul>
    <li id="one">
      <img src="images/1.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/2.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li id="two">
      <img src="images/3.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/4.jpg" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using a library for slider?

Comment: Yes i am using jquery for slider

Comment: This would depend on the code for your slider then

Comment: either add the plugin or make a working snippet

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am using slider from here.  https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/3D-Image-Slider-StackSlider.html               I need to go to a specific slider from another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackSlider cannot work with given parameter ,so you should 'fix it a little bit.

go to function _init within jquery.stackslider.js and instead of row:
this.current = 0;
place following:
if(!this.options.current)
    this.current = 0;
else
    this.current = this.options.current-1;

now you can pass initial parameter of which slide to show.

now your html should look like so->

```
 <a href="page.html#1">go to 1st slide of page.html</a><br>
    <a href="page.html#2">go to 2st slide of page.html</a><br>
    <a href="page.html#3">go to 3st slide of page.html</a>
```

and your page.html will look like-->

```
 <ul id="st-stack" class="st-stack-raw">
            <li id = "1">
                <div class="st-item"> <a href="http://drbl.in/fgQV"> <img src="images/fl1.jpg" /> </a> </div>
                <div class="st-title">
             image1
                </div></li>
                    <li id=2><div class="st-item st-center"> <a href="http://drbl.in/fgQV"> <img src="images/fl2.jpg" /> </a> </div>
                        <div class="st-title">
                        image2
                        </div></li>
                     <li id = "3"><div class="st-item"> <a href="http://drbl.in/fgQV"> <img src="images/fl3.jpg" /> </a> </div>
                        <div class="st-title">
                        image3
                        </div></li>

            </ul>

<script type=text/javascript>
  //passing parameter from hash
  var img2show = parseInt((location.hash || 5).split('#')[1]);
        $( '#st-stack' ).stackslider({"current":img2show});

    </script>
```

Comment: You don't need to modify the plugin. it already implemented `start` as option so you can pass the param for hash to it.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is not reading the hash value, that's why it's not working. BUT, you can pass the wanted slide with the hash and pass it to the plugin via the `start` options. Something like this:

```js
var start = location.hash || 5;

$('#st-stack').stackslider({
  start: start
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/codrops/StackSlider/778ed3b9963a9cae2bf41c07b292a80cf30ffbaa/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/codrops/StackSlider/778ed3b9963a9cae2bf41c07b292a80cf30ffbaa/js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/codrops/StackSlider/778ed3b9963a9cae2bf41c07b292a80cf30ffbaa/js/jquery.stackslider.js"></script>

<section class="main">
  <ul id="st-stack" class="st-stack-raw">
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fgQV"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/1.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Graverobber</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fpRz"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/2.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Hideous Snake Queen</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fGVs"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/3.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Queen of Hearts</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fgvZ"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/4.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Dead Pirate vs Kraken</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fyfM"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/5.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Mountain Lion</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fCmJ"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/6.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Flying Skull</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fsMv"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/7.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>The Fly &amp; Bureaucratic Elephant</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fGOf"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/8.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Failsnake</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fypr"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/9.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Cultist</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fEmG"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/10.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Crusader &amp; Viking</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/ffiw"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/11.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Crocodile</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fqWx"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/12.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Captain Banana</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fkuv"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/13.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Werewolf</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="st-item">
        <a href="http://drbl.in/fIli"><img src="//tympanus.net/Development/StackSlider/images/14.jpg" /></a>
      </div>
      <div class="st-title">
        <h2>Vegetables</h2>
        <h3>by Isaac Montemayor</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <p>Tip: to see a continuous flow, keep your mouse pressed on the navigation arrows.</p>
</section>
```

I just put 5 by default so you could see the effect but in your project, if you will redirect the user with the slide in the `hash` it will work for you without the default value.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :D

Comment: @rizbanulhasan Sure :) Have you tried my solution? You don't need to modify anything in the plugin's script. Only do what I I showed you.

Comment: Yes i tried but it unfortunately it takes to the first slide, not the slide i want. May be i am missing something?

Comment: Can be. Is your project public? Can you send me a URL?

Comment: I am working locally. It is not online yet. I will upload it asap and send you the link. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Sure. I'm happy to help :)